# Re-write LINQ outer join with method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have this working outer join query:

```
var outerJoin = from b in books
                join p in publishers on b.PublisherName equals p.Name into joinedPublishers
                from publisher in joinedPublishers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { b.Title, PublisherName = (publisher == null ? "No publisher" : publisher.Name) };
```

I'm trying to produce the same with the method syntax. Thus far I have this:

```
outerJoin = books.GroupJoin(publishers, b => b.PublisherName, p => p.Name, (b, group) => new { b.Title, PublisherName = group.DefaultIfEmpty()});
```

However, `group` is `IEnumerable`, when I need a string for the publisher name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you can call

```
{
    b.Title,
    PublisherName = group.Any()?group.First().Name: "No publisher";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to figure it out with the following:

```
outerJoin = books.GroupJoin(publishers, 
                            b => b.PublisherName, 
                            p => p.Name, 
                            (b, publisherGroup) => new { b.Title, publisherGroup})
                 .SelectMany(x => x.publisherGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                            (x, y) => new {x.Title, PublisherName = (y == null ? "No publisher" : y.Name)});
```